# Рекурсия в классах (бесконечный цикл)

Tags: python, рекурсия

Пытаюсь написать консольную версию морского боя. Написал вот такой код:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.menu = Menu()


class Menu(Game):
    def start(self):
        print('Добро пожаловать в игру "Морской бой"')
        self.show_menu_commands()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
  File "C:/111222333_installed_files/Programs/Py Charm/Sea Fights/main.py", line 111, in <module>
    game = Game()
  File "C:/111222333_installed_files/Programs/Py Charm/Sea Fights/main.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.menu = Menu()
  File "C:/111222333_installed_files/Programs/Py Charm/Sea Fights/main.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.menu = Menu()
  File "C:/111222333_installed_files/Programs/Py Charm/Sea Fights/main.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.menu = Menu()
  [Previous line repeated 496 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Пытался гуглить решение - ничего не нашел. Как я понял, класс запускает рекурсию, но какого черта - без понятия. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Класс Menu наследует Game, то есть наследует его инициализатор (__init__)
Явно это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.menu = Menu() # тут вызывается инициализатор Menu


class Menu(Game):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # тут вызывается инициализатор Game

    def start(self):
        print('Добро пожаловать в игру "Морской бой"')
        self.show_menu_commands()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
```

Рекурсия очевидна